# Diagnostic/Benchmarking tool to embed in WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, benchmarking, diagnostics

**I want to add a diagnostics screen to my application** which would test resources like RAM, CPU, WPF performance and compare it to a benchmark.

I am looking for a library or open source project that makes it easy to get a baseline of computing performance (RAM, CPU, GPU, etc) to compare fast machines with slow machines, with a goal of identifying the source of performance problems.  **I aim to get a high-level answer of which computing resource may be causing a slowdown.**  This would help focus troubleshooting efforts in the right direction.

I am imagining something like a cross between a standard computer hardware / network performance benchmark tool, crossed with [DxDiag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DxDiag) (for DirectX) which measures the time it takes to render a bouncing ball, etc.

The ideal solution would be written in .net and have these built in:

- WPF Rendering/shading speed test.
- CPU speed test
- Network (LAN) speed test (throughput and latency)
- RAM speed test
- Display the memory used by the application, and how much memory is available.

**What open source project or off-the-shelf library do you recommend?**

**Additional Information:**

My application is used by professionals, contains mostly textual information, a few icons, plenty of shading and a few little mouse-activated animation effects here and there.  I aim to get a high-level answer of which computing resource may be causing a slowdown.

Comment: you could just add some Windows Performance Counters for stuff that is not already available as a performance counter.
For displaying used memory you could query System.GC for used "managed" memory. This does not show any native resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything quite like what I'm looking for, however, [this article](http://www.japf.fr/2009/10/measure-rendering-time-in-a-wpf-application/) may prove useful, as it shows how to measure how long it takes to render some WPF.

Answer (score 1):

It's not for embedding, but are you aware of the [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx)?

Comment: +1 Thanks, this may be helpful for evaluating older versions before I add the benchmark functionality to the app.

Answer (score 1):

For Vista machines and higher you can access the Windows Experience Index scores.  This would give you a high level glance on what could be the bottleneck on a system (CPU, video card, memory, or disk drive).

Each time a test is done it creates a file in %Windows%\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\

You can simply check for the one with the most recent timestamp and read the values directly.  Just read the elements between the  tags.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the machines are Windows XP, but good suggestion.